# spacemacs - Map single evil keypress to multiple keystrokes

Tags: spacemacs

I'm a Vim user trying out spacemacs for the first time. In Vim, I have a keybind that when I press L (jump to bottom of screen), it also centers the screen on the cursor. In my .vimrc, this is done with `nnoremap L L<bar>zz <CR>`, but I'm unsure of how to chain two keypresses like this in emacs.

Comment: The Emacs way is to write a custom command instead of coming up with a sequence of keystrokes.  Therefore there's no general answer to this type of question as every situation requires its own special command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Emacs the standard practice is to write an elisp function to do this sort of thing. For instance, you could implement your command and bind it like this:

```
(defun center-last-line ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (beginning-of-line)
  (recenter))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c l") #'center-last-line)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look more into elisp functions. This worked function worked as well.